# Data structure for "interpolated" table lookup

Tags: performance, language-agnostic, data-structures

I have a collection of 2-D points which represent a 1-variable function.
Given a random input value, I have to select the closest value.
Example:

Curve:
(1,5)
(2,8)
(5,9)

Input: 3 Output: 8

My main concern is speed, space doesn't matter as much.
Which data structure would be best?

**EDIT**: The table is static, it won't change during runtime

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends upon whether the table is static or dynamic.

If it's static data, simple sorted array and binary search will get the job done: search for the key, if it isn't found, check the index above and below to see which is closer to the search key, and return its associated value.

If the data is dynamic, I'd go with a B+Tree variant (though any balanced tree structure should work). Essentially the same algorithm, but you'd be checking sibling nodes, instead of just checking adjacent array cells.

Answer (score 1):

You say the table is static, and won't change during runtime.
Then if you need blazing performance, and if the table is not too large, it's hard to beat a hard-coded binary search.
For the table you gave, it looks like this:

```
result = (x < 3.5
            ? (x < 1.5
                ? 5
                : 8
              )
            : 9
         );
```

You may have to write a little program to take the table as input, and generate the code as output, so you can include it in your main program.

If you don't mind using a macro, you might make it a little easier to write, like this:

```
#define M(a,middle,b) (x < (middle) ? (a) : (b))

result = M( M(5, 1.5, 8), 3.5, 9);
```

The only way to beat that is with a hard-coded hash search (using a switch statement).

If the table can change between runs, it might make sense to, whenever the program starts, it generates the code, compiles and links it into a dll, loads the dll, and runs with that.
That can take all of about a second, and then you have the high speed.